# Phpfox include php file that runs in every page

Tags: php, jquery, phpfox

I want a php file to be automatically included in every phpfox page even login page 
I tried using some hooks but failed.

Can hooks do it or I must hardcode it and change some phpfox files ??

Comment: You can set an [auto_prepend](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) file in your php.ini

Comment: I need it in only pages and not ajax request

Comment: Then you auto prepend a short file that provides some if test to check if it's an ajax request; and if not you can then include the main file that you want to include

Answer (score 0):

You can include hard-coded in `template.html.php` in your theme directory.